# How to make a scroll with a glow effect

Tags: css

I wrote such a scroll, but the box-shadow is drawn with a delay every few seconds, how can I make the glow effect stable

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
</body>
<style>
    body{
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .main {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 50vmin;
        height: 50vmin;
    }

    .main::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5vmin;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 5vmin;
    }

    .main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: blue;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5vmin 5vmin rgb(109, 93, 255);
        border-radius: 5vmin;
    }
    .child{
        height:200%;
        width:10%;
    }



</style>

</html>
```

Also, draw delays are present on other divs on which the shadow falls.

You can force the browser to redraw by moving focus to and from another application.

Comment: Just an observation, that if you try to force some sort of reflow, e.g. by animating main, part of the shadow moves, the other not (at least on Windows10 Chrome). Apparently styling scrollbar and thumb is not on a standards track (and not in FF) so maybe implementations are rather flakey.